# Is there any inexpensive software that will let me analyse WiFi networks?

Tags: wifi

I'm designing antennas and need to test their signal strength.

I found [Tamograph](http://www.tamos.com/products/wifi-site-survey/) which does that analysis, but it costs too much for my budget, which is about 100$.

Does anyone know of cheaper software that checks Wifi signal strength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at two products from [Ekanau](http://www.ekahau.com/):

1. [Heatmapper](http://www.ekahau.com/wifidesign/ekahau-heatmapper)

   - Free
   - Export only as screenshots
   - Map Signal Coverage
   - Check settings
   - Find WiFi networks
     [image]
2. [Site Survey](http://www.ekahau.com/wifidesign/ekahau-site-survey)

   - Charged for but 30 day evaluation available
   - Lots of additional features
   - Custom reports
     [image]
3. Mobile Survey

   - Not free but 3 day evaluation available
   - Use Android Tablet or Phone for the survey
   - Export and share to desktop options
     [image]

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Barnes for your answer, i can't upvote your answer because im new here. But in this case, i need the full report with virtual APs... the heat mapper doesn't support. And the site survey program just let the clients to use it for 5 mins sequential, after 5 mins it will pop up the "please restart the software..." message! And the android app reports aren't useful without the Windows app... im really confused to find some same apps. But whatever thank you for your answer.